# Ссылка для перехода на сайте по кнопке

Tags: html, html5

на сайте есть кнопка, вот ее код

`<div class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" onclick="Cr(1)">Перейти</div>`

сайт допустим называет www.ru (как пример)

можно ли создать ссылку кликнув по которой произойдет переход и клик на сайте по этой кнопке, что указана выше?

Comment: <div class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" onclick="Ch">Перейти</div>

Comment: А обязательно ли делать клик после перехода? Нельзя просто сделать редирект сразу на нужный элемент?

Comment: а если кнопка завершает действие и никуда не ведет? допустим как кнопка = в калькуляторе

Comment: Переместите код кнопки из комментария в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь правильно понял суть вопроса.
Если использовать jquery:

```
<div id="some" data-href="www.ru" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" onclick="Ch">Перейти</div>

<script>
$('#some').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
//Сделать необходимое действие
//
//перейти по ссылке
location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
});
</script>
```

Или просто вставить ссылку и все

```
<a href="www.ru" target="_blank" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12">Кнопка</a>
```

Comment: не нужна ссылка просто вида
www.ru/#onclick="Ch"
или что-то такое, или так не работает?

Comment: Это не корректно, тогда желательно передать get параметры в ссылке. Пример: **www.ru?onclick=ch** , если будет несколько параметров, тогда : **www.ru?onclick=ch&twoclick=ch**. и на самой странице в зависимости от параметра, который пришел урл выполнить действие.